# Java Spring simple HTML Link

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am fairly new to Spring Webapplication and need to do a little project for university. Currently I have a simple html site that displays some Data that I manually inserted into the database.

Now I am currently working on a new html file to insert Data through a seperate form.
On my "main" page I have a navbar, where I want to click on an item and get redirected to a specific page.
I tried redirecting the link directly to an html file in my resources folder, but it doesnt seem to work.

```
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/inputbook.html">Add Book <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```

I also tried to link it by:

- "${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/inputbook.html" (Found that in another thread)
- "./inputbook.html"
- "../inputbook.html"

Is there a way to simply link this page or do I need to make an action + a method in a Controller?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

Something interresting just happened. I added the method to map the site in my controller. 
When I try to open this site through the navbar, it tells me that it isnt mapped. Now (for testing, I have the form from the "inputbook.html" file also in my main page) when I input data through the main pages form, it saves it to the database and displays it correctly. After this process when I click on the Nav Bar again, it opens the "inputbook.html" site without any problems?

Controller:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {
private final BookService bookService;
private final BookRepository bookRepository;

@GetMapping
public String showBooks(Model model) {
    List<Book> books = bookService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("books",books);
    return "books"; //view name
}

@PostMapping(value="/search")
public String serachByTitle(Model model, @RequestParam Optional<String> searchTerm) {//Parameter heißt wie Feld in html form
    List<Book> books = searchTerm.map(bookService::findByTitleLike)
            .orElseGet(bookService::findAll);
    model.addAttribute("searchTerm",searchTerm.get());
    model.addAttribute("books",books);
    return "books";
}

@GetMapping("inputbook.html")
public String inputbook() {
    return "inputbook"; // this returns the template name to be rendered from resources/templates. You don't need to provide the extension.
}
@PostMapping(value="/insert")
public String insertBook(Model model,@RequestParam String title) {
    Book book = Book.builder()
            .title(title)
            .description("beschreibung")
            .author("auth" )
            .isbn(12353)
            .creator("creator") // fake it till spring security
            .creationTS(LocalDateTime.MIN)
            .publisher("pub")
            .available(true)
            .deliveryTimeDay(2)
            .build();
    bookRepository.save(book);
    return showBooks(model);
}
```

}

books.html("Main" Page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="inputbook.html">Add Book <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" th:action="@{/books/search}">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label th:for="searchTerm">Searchterm</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="searchTerm">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
        </form>

        **<form method="post" th:action="@{/books/insert}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label th:for="title">Titel</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="title">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>**
        <table  class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>CreationTS</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Creator</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr th:each="book : ${books}">
                    <td th:text="${book.title}">Betreff</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.creationTS}">2018-01-01 10:01:01</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.author}">TestAuthor</td>
                    <td th:text="${book.creator}">TestCreator</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

inputbook.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Books</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" th:action="@{/books/insert}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="title">Titel</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:name="title">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and cleanest way is to define a simple Spring Controller to handle the request. So the HTML File will be rendered. 
What template engine are you using? Are you using Spring Boot? Do you have the code anywhere?

Sample for such a controller:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

  @GetMapping("inputbook.html")
  public String inputbook() {
    return "inputbook"; // this returns the template name to be rendered from resources/templates. You don't need to provide the extension.
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Michael, Thank you for your help! I Am using Thymeleaf. What code should I post? My Controller and the html file?

Comment: Something interresting just happened.. I added your method to my controller to map "inputbook.html". When I try to open this site through the navbar, it tells me that it isnt mapped. Now (for testing, I have the form from the "inputbook.html" file also in my main page) when I input data through the main pages form, it saves it to the database and displays it correctly. After this process when I click on the Nav Bar again, it opens the "inputbook.html" site without any problems? I will update my post with the html files and my controller

Comment: It somehow just worked properly once I commented out the form i had on the main page. Thanks!

Comment: hmm strange, sometimes it works and sometimes the mapping doesnt work. I think it depends on what path I currently am at. When i startup the application and try to click on the link, it doesnt work. As soon as I click my search button, and click on the link afterwards, it works properly...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have a method in controller which is mapped to this URL `/inputbook.html` and returning the page which you want to see like below.

```
@GetMapping("inputbook.html")
  public String method() {
    return "inputbook.html"; //extension depends on view resolver.
}
```

If you dont want to do any business logic before loading the page than you need now to create a method in controller can directly use like below.

**XML configuration (Spring-mvc):**

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/"view-name="index"/>
```

**Annotation configuration (Spring-boot):**

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
}
```

Comment: Something interresting just happened.. I added your method to my controller to map "inputbook.html". When I try to open this site through the navbar, it tells me that it isnt mapped. Now (for testing, I have the form from the "inputbook.html" file also in my main page) when I input data through the main pages form, it saves it to the database and displays it correctly. After this process when I click on the Nav Bar again, it opens the "inputbook.html" site without any problems? I will update my post with the html files and my controller

Comment: It somehow just worked properly once I commented out the form i had on the main page. Thanks!